# Leer la información de multiples archivos de texto

Tags: java, excel, vba

Tengo una codigo vba (macro) en la que tengo que copiar el contenido de cada archivo de texto y pegarlo en una hoja de excel para que lo lea, elimine las lineas que no son necesarias y mediante formulas (extrae) obtenga los datos que necesito.

El problema es que tengo que hacer esto con cada documento y luego con esos datos armar una tabla, lo que me quema tiempo. ¿Saben de algún codigo que pueda usar, de preferencia java, que pueda leer la informacion de esos archivos en conjunto?